# Giving error on using async/await in jasmine-protractor functions

Tags: angular, eclipse, async-await, jasmine, protractor

I am doing an e2e testing on my angular site using protractor-jasmine. On using async functions and await for rest of the code returning promise is giving error in Jasmine-protractor.

I even included: `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,`

```
it('Sub-folder: Manage permission, Edit Folder name, Create Template, View Template', async ()=> {
await obj.getURL();
obj.TealoginUname.sendKeys(data.uname);
obj.TealoginPass.sendKeys(data.pass);
await obj.TealoginButton.click();
await browser.sleep(2000);
})
```

Console Error:

```
Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
```

In eclipse it's showing error on those lines where `async`/`await` are written.
[image]

I am using Page object model for dynamic elements. 
`var obj=  require("./somefile.js");`

somefile.js:-

```
function  globalVariables()
{
this.TealoginUname= element(by.model("vm.login.userid"));
this.TealoginPass= element(by.model("vm.login.password"));
this.TealoginButton= element(by.xpath("//*[@id='login-form']/form[1]/button"));

}
```

Comment: What is `obj` supposed to be?

Comment: I am using Page object model for dynamic data and elements. I have updated my question to include that as well.

Answer (score 0):

without importing the locators add it in your test file

```
const TealoginUname= element(by.model("vm.login.userid"));
const TealoginPass= element(by.model("vm.login.password"));
const TealoginButton= element(by.xpath("//*[@id='login-form']/form[1]/button"));
```

Try the below one

```
it('Sub-folder: Manage permission, Edit Folder name, Create Template, View Template', async ()=> {
await broswer.get('add your url here');
await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true); // To make protractor wait for all the http request to get compelted
await TealoginUname.sendKeys(data.uname);
await TealoginPass.sendKeys(data.pass);
await TealoginButton.click();
await browser.sleep(2000);
})
```

Comment: still same error. I tried the updated code using 'const'.

Comment: Share your implementation. try `var` instead of `const`